# Find the largest positive integer $n$ such that $n^3 + 100$ is divisible by $n+10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences

I'm still kinda new to number theory so could someone tell me if my solution is right?

Reducing $\mod n +10$ 
$$n \equiv -10 \pmod{n+10} \implies n^3 + 100 \equiv -900 \pmod{n+10}$$
So we want $(n+10) \mid 900$ and the largest number would be $n = 890$

Comment: $\frac{n^3+100}{n+10}=n^2-10n+100-\frac{900}{n+10}$. So yes, $890$ is the largest integer value of $n$ such that the entire expression is also integer.

Comment: @barakmanos Thank you!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124927/what-is-the-largest-positive-n-for-which-n3100-is-divisible-by-n10